# Server.userException when sending a SOAP-Request with VBScript

Tags: soap, vbscript

When sending a SOAP-Request the answer XML contains a Server.userException faultstring
`<faultstring>No such operation 'TabellenExport'</faultstring>`
As far a i know this is not specific to the web service i am trying to reach. My suspicion is, that i am doing something wrong when creating the Request and setting the headers.

```
Dim http, soapRequest
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
    
http.open "POST", wsdl, False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
http.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", url
    
http.send xml
request = http.responseText
```

This is the XML i´m sending:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice_2010.genesis">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:TabellenExport soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <kennung xsi:type="xsd:string">*********</kennung>
         <passwort xsi:type="xsd:string">********</passwort>
         <namen xsi:type="xsd:string">61111-0002</namen>
         <bereich xsi:type="xsd:string">Alle</bereich>
         <format xsi:type="xsd:string">xml</format>
         <strukturinformation xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</strukturinformation>
         <komprimieren xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</komprimieren>
         <transponieren xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</transponieren>
         <startjahr xsi:type="xsd:string"></startjahr>
         <endjahr xsi:type="xsd:string"></endjahr>
         <zeitscheiben xsi:type="xsd:string"></zeitscheiben>
         <regionalmerkmal xsi:type="xsd:string"></regionalmerkmal>
         <regionalschluessel xsi:type="xsd:string"></regionalschluessel>
         <sachmerkmal xsi:type="xsd:string"></sachmerkmal>
         <sachschluessel xsi:type="xsd:string"></sachschluessel>
         <sachmerkmal2 xsi:type="xsd:string"></sachmerkmal2>
         <sachschluessel2 xsi:type="xsd:string"></sachschluessel2>
         <sachmerkmal3 xsi:type="xsd:string"></sachmerkmal3>
         <sachschluessel3 xsi:type="xsd:string"></sachschluessel3>
         <stand xsi:type="xsd:string"></stand>
         <auftrag xsi:type="xsd:boolean"></auftrag>
         <sprache xsi:type="xsd:string">de</sprache>
      </web:TabellenExport>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It is according to the documentation that is available to me.

The WSDL is located here: https://www-genesis.destatis.de/genesisWS/services/ExportService_2010?wsdl
i tried switching the url and the wsdl but i got the same result.
Am i doing something wrong?

wsdl is the location of the WSDL-File, url ist the target address provided to me by the web service and xml is juste the text of the xml i wont to send.

Comment: The error is saying that the operation defined in the SOAP XML `TabellenExport` is not a defined operation, check your spelling and maybe supply the XML in the question would help, maybe even the WSDL.

Comment: What are you passing as the `SOAPAction` header?

Comment: How old is your Apache Axis installation?, [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3941854/692942).

Comment: The documentation, that is available to me, for the webservice i am trying to reach does not contain any information about headers, so at this point nothing.
Also, as far as i know, i do not use Apache Axis.

Comment: Just look at the [WSDL file](https://www-genesis.destatis.de/genesisWS/services/ExportService_2010?wsdl) `<!-- WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.3` think that is pretty telling, it quite clearly is using Apache Axis.